# Iframe links not to open in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

i have iframe that shows content from the page that is not mine. In that iframe exists some links. When user clicks on links, they open inside iframe. I want them to open in current window (parent window).

I have found solution to add

```
 target="_parent"
```

to links, but i cant do that, becouse iframed page is not mine, and i cant edit that page.

Is there some way to do this, to open links from iframe in parent window?

Or js/jquery code to find all links on that page and add them attribut target?

Comment: Well, there is not much to put here: just one iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatley it is not possible to query the content of an `<iframe>` which origin is from a different server. The only thing what you could do is to "proxy" the page through a server-side script (with PHP or something) before outputting it:

- request the page using "[cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php)" or something similar
- parse the content for your needs (like setting the `target`-attribute on all links)
- output it back to the page's iframe

Finally the `<iframe>` could look like this: `<iframe src="myproxy.php"></iframe>`